# How to show multiple tabbed content sections?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website with three sections containing tabbed areas. I had an older version of this which worked fine, and showed all sections correctly at all times, however as I was changing to a new layout the tabbed sections stopped functioning, I then changed them to some new code and ended up preferring this instead. I then noticed that my content would only show in one section at a time, so some sections do not show up when the page is loaded, unless the tab link is active/clicked.

I recall finding a way to fix this before but I've looked online and can't find anything, and didn't save a version of my old JS code to refer back to. I was hoping someone could help me remember why this happens and how to fix it.

I should note that I have unique IDs for my code and I have not reflected this in my code, as I had that issue the first time round. The unique IDs do not help fix the issue unfortunately.

```js
function openPage(pageName, elmnt, color) {
  // Hide all elements with class="tabcontent" by default */
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Remove the background color of all tablinks/buttons
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }

  // Show the specific tab content
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";

  // Add the specific color to the button used to open the tab content
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Serif', sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.new-section__black {
  padding: 5%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Style tab links */

.tablink {
  float: left;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 1%;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 10%;
}

.link-black {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.link-white {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.tablink:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.tablink:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.link-black:active,
.link-black:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #555;
}

.link-white:active,
.link-white:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}


/* Style the tab content (and add height:100% for full page content) */

.tabcontent {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding: 100px 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.content-black {
  color: #000;
}

.content-white {
  color: #fff;
}

.tabcontent .col:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#defaultOpen {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="card new-section__black new_section">

  <button class="tablink link-white" onclick="openPage('Tab1', this)" id="defaultOpen">
                    <h3>Tab1</h3>
                </button>
  <button class="tablink link-white" onclick="openPage('Tab2', this)">
                    <h3>Tab2</h3>
                </button>
  <button class="tablink link-white" onclick="openPage('Tab3', this)">
                    <h3>Tab3</h3>
                </button>
  <button class="tablink link-white" onclick="openPage('Tab4', this)">
                    <h3>Tab4</h3>
                </button>

  <div id="Tab1" class="tabcontent content-white">
    <div class="col span-2-of-2">
      <h2>Tab1</h2>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Tab2" class="tabcontent content-white">
    <div class="col span-2-of-2">
      <h2>Tab2</h2>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Tab3" class="tabcontent content-white">
    <div class="col span-2-of-2">
      <h2>Tab3</h2>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Tab4" class="tabcontent content-white">
    <div class="col span-2-of-2">
      <h2>Tab4</h2>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/caitlinmooneyx/pen/OKyoLE) example of what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple sets of "tabs" on the page, you need to scope your interactions to that specific `<section>`.

```
function openPage(pageName, elmnt, color) {
  // Get the parent node, make all DOM selections based on this
  var section = elmnt.parentElement;

  // Hide all elements with class="tabcontent" by default */
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = section.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Remove the background color of all tablinks/buttons
  tablinks = section.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }

  // Show the specific tab content
  section.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";

  // Add the specific color to the button used to open the tab content
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

Also, you repeat element `id` values everywhere, this is not proper HTML and will lead to unexpected behavior. Each `id` should be unique. (you currently have multiple "defaultOpen" elements, you have multiple "Tab1", "Tab2", etc... rename them with no repeated values)

Comment: Yes sorry I should have mentioned the IDs are all unique on my own one and still do not work. I noticed that early on and changed them as I thought that was the issue but it did not fix the issue unfortunately.

Comment: The defaultOpen element however, I need that to be there as without it the tabs malfunction (they did this in my old version) and show the wrong tab on page load.